# How to draw pressure lines in Illustrator with a Surface Pro

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I want to draw lines like the one located on the left side, but what I get when I try drawing are the lines located at the right side. As you can see, the ends arent sharp but round and it doesn't have the same effect as going from thin to thick.

I am working on a Microsoft Surface pro 4.

[image]

Comment: Is the Microsoft Surface Pro 4 pressure sensitive? Probably not. Then you'd need a pressure sensitive graphic tablet. Or use a Variable Width Profile, which will create the wanted shape without pressure.

Comment: @AAGD yes it is. Anyway for presuresensitivity to work well you need to adjust its settings to suit your normal hand pressure

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because it is the same question you previously asked. Please edit your original question to add clarity. In addition, this would appear to be an issue with the Surface Pro, not Illustrator and therefore SuperUser.com may be a more appropriate site to ask. In short, there's *nothing* in your brush set up that should *not* be reading pressure in Illustrator. Clearly it's a hardware issue and outside the scope of general graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're aiming to get actually just looks like a pressure-sensitive brush stroke. May be someone could recreate that with a tablet, but it's really difficult to get those sharp edges by varying real pen pressure.

What you are to do with your path(s) selected:

1. First change "Brush Definition" to "Basic" (the drop-down on the right of my screenshot);
2. Than choose "Width Profile 1" in a "Variable Width Profile" drop-down (the one on the left).

That will make both edges go perfectly sharp

[image]

Comment: This *won't* read pressure at all.  It may achieve the sharp capped paths, but t's not the same as drawing with pressure.

Comment: Exactly, but nonetheless it will look same as the leftmost stroke from Blank's initial screenshot